# My Query is getting failed with the following Deadlock error:

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, transactions, deadlock

"Transaction (Process ID 99) was deadlocked on lock resources with another process and has been chosen as the deadlock victim. Rerun the transaction."  This is the error  I'm getting, but sometimes the query runs fine and gives the correct result but sometimes it gives a Deadlock error. Don't have any idea why is it is falling. If sometimes it runs fine.

```
 select  
    ACC_ID into
    #Accounts
    from
    Member
    group by ACC_ID
    having count(*)>1
    
    
    select ACC_ID,min(Amount) as min_Amount
    into  #Accounts_2
     from
    Member
    where ACC_ID in (select ACC_ID from #Accounts)
    group by ACC_ID
    
    
    select m.ACC_ID,h.min_Amount,sum(cus_Amount) as new_cus_Amount
    into #Accounts_3
     from
    Member M
    join #Accounts_2 h
    on M.ACC_ID=H.ACC_ID and M.Amount=h.min_Amount
    group by m.ACC_ID,h.min_Amount
    
    update M
    set M.acc_Amount=h.new_cus_Amount ,
    M.acc_AmountNew=h.min_Amount
    from #Accounts_3 h
    join
    Member M
    on M.ACC_ID=H.ACC_ID and M.Amount=h.min_Amount
    
    
    Drop table #Accounts
    Drop table #Accounts_2
    Drop table #Accounts_3
```

Comment: Do you have a deadlock graph then we can give answer more proper answer.  https://www.sqlshack.com/what-are-sql-server-deadlocks-and-how-to-monitor-them/

Comment: To help us craft an information appropriate response, do you understand what a deadlock is within the context of database queries? That's not intended as an insult, simply to help level set expectations